# Why was I awarded Special Bonus points?

Tags: atari-50-anniversary-celebration, maze-invaders

One time while playing Maze Invaders, after I collected every fruit in a maze I got 2500 extra points as a "Special Bonus". I haven't been able to make this happen again. What did I do to get this Special Bonus?

[image: Special Bonus 2500]